# ElasticSearch as a source for FluentD

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

Is there any way to setup ElasticSearch as a source for Fluentd?
All documentations describes how to set ES as a destination but I have some data which has to be processed by Fluentd and delivered to kafka topic.

ES -> Fluentd -> Kafka

Comment: How would this data be sent to fluentd? In what format and by which communication channel?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a fluentd http input plugin for this.

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fluent-plugin-http-pull/0.8.3

I could not try it directly but here is a sample configuration :

```
<source>
    @type http_pull

    tag status
    url http://your-cluster:9200/your-index/_search
    interval 10s

    format json
</source>
```

You can send a post request, too.

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fluent-plugin-http-pull/0.8.3#http_method-enum-optional-default-get

I think this is good for time series data and you can fetch the data with filtering recent data on search and the plugin will fetch them every 10 seconds, etc or what ever range you want. But I could not realize how you can do a pagination already indexed data.